# PATCH vs POST - Increment Counter

Tags: rest, restful-url

Two questions regarding incrementing a single value in a Restful manner

Let's say we have the following Table.

```
public class EmployeeStatistics   
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int CallsMade { get; set; }
    public int CallsRecieved { get; set; }
}
```

**Question #1**

What would be the correct format to increment the `CallsMade` field?

A: `api/EmployeeStatistics/AddCallMade/EmpId/{empId}`

B: `api/EmployeeStatistics/EmpId/{empId}/AddCallMade`

**Question #2**

POST or PATCH?

There are conflicting answers online regarding this question.

While PATCH is used to replace specific values, I'm not looking to supply a payload containing the final value, rather I'd like to trigger a server side event that increments the specified value and returns status code `200` on completion.

If my understanding is correct, incrementing a value is not idempotent as the result changes each time the operation is run. This leads me to believe POST would be the correct solution.

All answers and opinions appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> POST or PATCH?

"It depends".  [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789), like [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4), describes a change to a representation in a domain agnostic way.  You are, in effect, telling the server "modify your copy of the resource so that it looks like *this*.

Most PATCH formats don't offer an "increment" operation; what you get are `set` or [replace](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.3) semantics (just as is true of PUT).  Expressed in JSON PATCH, you would normally see an operation like

```
{ "op": "replace", "path": "/CallsMade", "value": 42 }
```

Or, if you are trying to ensure that there are no lost edits

```
{ "op": "test", "path": "/CallsMade", "value": 41 }
{ "op": "replace", "path": "/CallsMade", "value": 42 }
```

PATCH also has atomic change semantics

> The server MUST apply the entire set of changes atomically and never provide (e.g., in response to a GET during this operation) a partially modified representation.

So if you can't actually ensure that the changes are going to be all or nothing; if you can't put all of the changes into a single "transaction", then PATCH is the wrong idea.

That said, everything you can do with PATCH can also be done with POST -- POST just offers fewer guarantees.

> What would be the correct format to increment the CallsMade field?

PATCH, like PUT and DELETE, describes a change to the representation of a resource.  The usual rhythm would be something like

```
GET /X
(edit)
PATCH /X
```

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your identifiers, so all of the following options are equally acceptable

```
api/EmployeeStatistics/AddCallMade/EmpId/{empId}
api/EmployeeStatistics/EmpId/{empId}/AddCallMade
api/EDA9E9D4-EC6D-4884-91A6-F15BCE88D060
```

We normally use [path segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) for hierarchical data, so you might use a target URI like this, if consumers were expecting to edit the entire EmployeeStatistic entity

```
api/EmployeeStatistics/{empId}
```

or a target URI like this, if you wanted to provide a resource limited to just the information associated with calls made

```
api/EmployeeStatistics/{empId}/callsMade
```

the results on your consumer's [caches](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) aren't quite the same, so you will need to think carefully about the grain of your resources.

With POST... well, with POST you can do almost anything; it's the get-out-of-jail-free card of HTTP methods.  There are still caching implications, but there is nothing fundamentally wrong with having a single resource that can increment the callsMade of any employee.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.

I'm thinking it may be best to add the EmployeeStatistics.CallsMade increment to the end of a new Call post request rather than have a unique resource to handle the value increment.